# Converting and printing array of hashes - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, scalar

I really dont know how to do it so I ended up here.

I want to convert this input:

```
my @sack_files_1 = (
    'mgenv/1_2_3/parent.dx_environment',
    'mgenv/1_2_3/doc/types.dat',
    'u5env/1_2_3/parent.dx_environment',
    'u5env/1_2_3/doc/types.dat',
);
```

To this:

```
my $sack_tree_1 = {
    'mgenv' => {
        '1_2_3' => [ 'parent.dx_environment', 'doc/types.dat' ],
    },
    'u5env' => {
        '1_2_3' => [ 'parent.dx_environment', 'doc/types.dat' ],
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @sack_files_1 = (
    'mgenv/1_2_3/parent.dx_environment',
    'mgenv/1_2_3/doc/types.dat',
    'u5env/1_2_3/parent.dx_environment',
    'u5env/1_2_3/doc/types.dat',
);

my %sack_tree_1;
foreach (@sack_files_1) {
    my ( $env, $number, @everything_else ) = split('/');
    push( @{ $sack_tree_1{$env}{$number} }, join( "/", @everything_else ) );
}

print Dumper \%sack_tree_1
```

Comment: `my ( $env, $number, $rest ) = split m#/#, $_, 3;`

Comment: All this time with perl - and I never realised there was a `LIMIT` option to split.

Comment: The simple and portable way of separating a path into steps is `File::Spec::splitpath`. This solution won't work outside a Linux-like file system.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `Data::Dump`, written by the author of the awesome `LWP` library, is far superior to `Data::Dumper`. It's not part of core Perl at present, but it's a pure-Perl module and will install on anything.

Comment: @Sobrique The LIMIT option is useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This will do as you ask. It uses [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec::Functions) to split each path into its components.

The first two elements of the hash are used directly as hash keys, relying on *autovivication* to create the necessary hash elements.

A simple `push` to an implied array reference also autovivifies the lowest-level hash element.

I have used [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) to display the resulting hash. It is not part of the core Perl installation and you may need to install it, but it is much superior to [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ splitdir catfile /;

my @sack_files_1 = (
  'mgenv/1_2_3/parent.dx_environment',
  'mgenv/1_2_3/doc/types.dat',
  'u5env/1_2_3/parent.dx_environment',
  'u5env/1_2_3/doc/types.dat',
);

my %paths;

for my $path (@sack_files_1) {
  my ($p1, $p2, @path) = splitdir $path;
  push @{ $paths{$p1}{$p2} }, catfile @path;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%paths;
```

**output**

```
{
  mgenv => { "1_2_3" => ["parent.dx_environment", "doc\\types.dat"] },
  u5env => { "1_2_3" => ["parent.dx_environment", "doc\\types.dat"] },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $sack_tree_1 = {};
foreach my $data (@sack_files_1) {
    my @path = split '/', $data;
    my ($file,$last_part) = pop @path, pop @path; # get the file name and last part of the path
    my $hash_part = $sack_tree_1;
    foreach my $path (@path) { # For every element in the remaining part of the path
        $hash_part->{$path} //= {}; # Make sure we have a hash ref to play with
        $hash_part = $hash_part->{$path} # Move down the hash past the current path element
    }
    $hash_part->{$last_part} = $file; # Add the file name to the last part of the path
 }
```

This handles all path lengths of 2 or more

Comment: I think you're needing a few more `%`s in there.

Comment: Really must read the question. This answers a completely different problem :-(

Comment: @JGNI: Splitting a path on slashes `/` is a non-expressive and Linux-specific way of splitting paths into their components. The [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec) module has always been part of core Perl 5, and the canonical way is to use `File::Spec->splitpath`

Comment: @Borodin Yer I know that, If you track down my one and only CPAN distribution You'll see I use File::Spec, but given the data and no other info I went for the simpler option. Also from the info given it's not 100% clear that those are file paths.